# Can we modify the "Cancel" and "Done" items of EKEventEditViewController to customise in an iphone application

Tags: ios7, eventkit

if anyone has  successfully modified these items, i need help to modify cancel and done UI in navigation bar with capital "CANCEL" and "DONE"  and custom fonts in an iphone application.

Comment: Please share some code snippet you already tried, it would give more broader idea to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am not getting your question exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy and paste below code into your ViewController through which you are presenting the EKEventEditController.

```
#pragma mark - Cancel/Done Events
-(void)cancelDidTapped:(UIBarButtonItem*)eventSender
{
   NSLog(@"left Click");
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
-(void)doneDidTapped:(UIBarButtonItem*)eventSender
{
   NSLog(@"right Click");
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
#pragma mark - Extra
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
    [viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:[@"cancel" uppercaseString] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDidTapped:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:[@"done" uppercaseString] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneDidTapped:)];


    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:btnCancel];
    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:btnDone];
    [viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Testing"];

}
```

Apart from that set the EKEventEditController delegate to self.

```
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
addController.delegate = self;
```

And you are good to go, cheers!!!